# Android bitmap in path

Tags: android, path, bitmap, imageview

I am wondering how to get the bitmap from specific location as follows:

```
    try {
      Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream)new URL("C:/java/AVMOrderServer/files/main_ads/fff.jpg").getContent());
      iv.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Any advice would be useful (I found the code sample on stackoverflow which is an answer voted as true)

Thank you all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Android device does not have a C drive, that's generally a DOS/Windows concept. Android is based on Linux. If you want to view a bitmap on your computer from your Android device you'll have to copy it over first, whether by including it in your APK or by copying to SD card.

Comment: Then is it possible to have the file in a path different than drawable/ such as data/images/blahblah.jpg

Comment: Here's the Android doc on [Data Storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html). You should find it informative.